# react-native payments Could not invoke React native payments

Tags: react-native

I integrated react-native-payments library to the my react native app and i have a run time error saying could not invoke ReactNativePayments.show [this is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x53M3.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** 
I think, I got the proper solution. Actually there is a problem with `ReactNativePayments.podspec` file, follow the below steps:

1. Run 
   `npm install react-native-payments --save`
2. Open `ReactNativePayments.podspec` file and some changes (**Refer screenshot below**)

[image: Screenshot 2019-09-23 at 12 52 21 PM]

3. Then run link command `react-native link react-native-payments`
4. Go to ios folder and run following command 
   `pod cache clean --all` and `pod install`

Please let me know if those solution help you.

Thanks 
**Alankar Saini**

Comment: It is a comment. It does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. Otherwise, it will be closed soon.

Comment: I am working on a android environment where can i find  ReactNativePayments.podspec file